# variable not resolve when pass through super from child class

Tags: angular, typescript, heroku

Here is my data Service class

```
import { BadInput } from './../common/bad-input';
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
 constructor(private url: string, private http: Http) { }

  getAll(obj) {
return this.http.post(this.url+"/get",obj)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
 customQuery(query) {
  console.log(this.url+"/dynamic/"+query);
return this.http.get(this.url+"/dynamic/"+query)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }
}
```

**Am using DataService in child class here**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "./data.service";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class ReasonsService extends DataService {
  constructor(http: Http) {
  super("xxx/v1/reasons", http);
 }
}
```

> ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in /tmp/build_b7eed86c18aa452fb03d88946e269f3a/toshikverma-rentitnow-df48c05/src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).

Here `URL` which is passed from child class in not resolved

I have gone through the answers mentioned on the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425139/angular2-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-iconservice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732585/angular-cli-2-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-xxxxx-by-aot-build), but didn't help me, I don't know what mistake am doing here,

```
 "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod",
```

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: try to remove `@Injectable()` from `DataService` and do not list `DataService` in the providers. IMO it's just a base class and Angular doesn't have to care about it.

Comment: @hgoebl thanks a lot sir you saved me I was trying to resolve this from past 2 days

Comment: I've added a complete answer because I think many might stumble over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It's sufficient to annotate only the derivations with `@Injectable` and list them in `providers[]`, not the base class.

#### Code

```
// NOTE: no @Injectable() here!
export class DataService { // might be abstract to reinforce meaning
  constructor(private url: string,
              protected http: Http) { }

  getAll(obj) { ... }
  customQuery(query) { ... }
}


@Injectable()
export class ReasonsService extends DataService {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    super("xxx/v1/reasons", http);
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

Your base class `DataService` is not a service instantiated and managed by Angular. It's just a base class for other services like your `ReasonsService`.

Because of that, your base class `DataService` must not have an `@Injectable()` annotation and should not be listed in `providers`.

In other words: inheriting from a base class has nothing to do with Angular, it's a TypeScript thing.

#### Comments

- You might consider declaring your base class as `abstract`. Through that everybody can see that this class will not be instantiated by its own and just serves as a base class.
- If you need members declared in the base class in your derivation, make them `protected` and not `private`. As an example, you can access the `http` service in the derivated class as well.